# Arima fitted values and plot values are different

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I want to store the estimated values predicted by ARIMA model. I am unable to view the values.
`model.predict` and `model.fittedvalues` is giving me the wrong values.

`model.plot_predict` predict is giving correct view on plot

```
model = ARIMA(df.data, order=best_order).fit()
model.plot_predict(dynamic=False, ax=ax)
```

[image: ARIMA Predict plot]

While my fitted values are showing in order of thousands
`model.fittedvalues`

```
1        819.779812
2      12228.575651
3      16196.594132
4      14240.383202
5      11240.214107
           ...     
323     3056.345112
324     2800.550610
325     3362.771562
326     3118.791960
327     1993.401574
Length: 327, dtype: float64
```

Comment: The estimated -- aka the fitted values -- are the expected value in the next period, and so tend to be shifted from the actual values by 1 observation.

Comment: @KevinS How can I view the values as shown in blue color in the graph?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the prediction in an object:

```
n = 20 #the number of observations to predict
preds = model.predict(n)
```

You can then print, plot or do whatever you want with the `preds` object

Comment: model. predict is giving future 20 observations.
I want to store the estimated values.

Comment: What do you mean by "estimated values"?